# How to open webpage in HIDDEN default browser? DELPHI

Tags: delphi, browser, hidden, shellexecute

I have been trying to open a hidden default browser from delphi but coulnd't.

I tried

```
ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open','www.google.com',nil,nil, SW_HIDE);
```

and I get my chrome browser open but not hidden, and it opens a tab not a new window, also tried with TStartupInfo with the same results. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Nothing that's guaranteed to work.  At the least, any browser that opens new URLs as tabs will ignore TStartupInfo.  Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Two reasons.  1, because the more information we have about what you're trying to do, the better answers we can give.  2, because trying to open a webpage and hide it from the user sounds kinda suspicious, and we're honorable coders here who don't want to help anyone write malware.  So please convince us you've got some legitimate reason to want to do this, or you're not likely to get any answers.

Comment: +1 @Mason. Same thoughts I had.