# How to open webpage in HIDDEN default browser, C++?

Tags: browser, default, hidden

**Disclaimer:**
I am aware there is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834597/how-to-open-webpage-in-hidden-default-browser-delphi) for this question but it has no answers. Craig Peterson, Mason Wheeler and other 13 people were wondering why the person who asked a question may need the answer. They said:

> because trying to open a webpage and hide it from the user sounds kinda suspicious, and we're honorable coders here who don't want to help anyone write malware. So please convince us you've got some legitimate reason to want to do this, or you're not likely to get any answers.

I tried to edit the original message in order to provide such reason and hopefully get the answer but the modification had been rejected by **dgw** and **albertjan**, saying:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post

So I am providing the reason for the question again, I believe it is pretty valid.

The reason:
This may be needed for running a specific Javascript lib, which cannot run on server. For example, for Google Analytics code, which must be run in the default browser (to avoid cookie confusion). And of course, we do not want to open any pages on user desktop although there is nothing to hide really.

Please advise.

Comment: i would rethink this if i was you, i don't know how you are going to use this cookies but in some areas like the Europe, the cookies are subjects to restrictions, you are probably breaking the law here, simply because with the phrase "to avoid cookie confusion" i think we can assume that you want to track and profile the user and his data.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean that GA is also breaking the law in Europe?

Comment: By cookie confusion I mean the following: we should open certain tracking pages under the same browser user downloaded our application (let's assume he/she uses the default browser in all cases). In contrast, if user downloaded application with the default browser but then IE/WebKit components are used to silently (**which is totally legal**) open those tracking pages then GA would treat a user as a new one.

Comment: I have a php that updates a database. It is on my site. Logging approved by user. A url with  params. This is why I would like hidden instance. User would be annoyed to see a browser pop up in their way.